# SSIS Overview report

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using SQL Server 2014 and save my SSIS packages to the Integration Services Catalog.  After my package executes (failure or success) it flashed up an "Overview" report.  Is there a way to have this report emailed to a distro list?

Comment: Not that I know of.   Here's a good place to start on something like it:   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140246(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not posible with this integrated report. But you can use a custom report like SSIS Reporting Pack by Jamie Thomson (Excellent reports in there) and use report suscription to do the job.

https://ssisreportingpack.codeplex.com/

You will have much more information about what happen and you will be able to customize.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you!  I will definitely give that a shot